# How do I set a field named by a string?

Tags: django, django-models

For a view that updates a model, I'd like to do something like this:

```
for field in ('name', 'parent', 'notes'):
    if request.POST[field]:
        myModel[field] = request.POST.get(field, '')
```

However, model's fields are accessed as properties (`myModel.field`), not dictionary items, and as far as I can tell there aren't get/set methods in Django models. Is there another way I can update these properties iteratively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)